# Formula for Stirling numbers expressed with Bernoulli numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, bernoulli-numbers

Is there a formula which expresses any of the Stirling numbers (1st or 2nd kind) in terms of the Bernoulli numbers? For example, here is the reverse

$$
B_k=\sum_{m=0}^{k} (-1)^m \frac{m!}{m+1}\sigma(k,m)
$$

where $\sigma(k,m)$ is the Stirling number of the 2nd kind

Comment: Well, one way is comparing the exp. generating function of negative Bernoulli with the one of Stirling numbers of second kind. But that seems like a pain to even write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, nobody answer this, so I am going to extend what I wrote in the comments.
We know that $$\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}=x^k\sum _{n\geq k}\sigma (n,k)\frac{x^{n-k}}{n!},$$ and that $$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum _{n = 0}^{\infty}B_n\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
So, to relate both we just manipulate the first equation to get
$$\frac{1}{\left (1-(1-\frac{x}{e^x-1})\right )^k}=\sum _{n\geq k}\sigma (n,k)\frac{x^{n-k}k!}{n!},$$ expanding the LHS one gets
$$\sum _{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}\left (-\sum _{\ell = 1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{\ell}}{\ell !}x^{\ell}\right )^m.$$ Expanding that one gets at the end that
$$\sigma (n,k)=\binom{n}{k}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}(-1)^m\sum _{x_1+\cdots +x_m=n-k}\binom{n-k}{x_1,\cdots ,x_m}\prod _{\ell = 1}^mB_{x_{\ell}}.$$
You can try a script to check this [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9UktugzAQ3XMKS93YZlAwVTdR3atUTmyo5Q-VM7l_bYcEUNPOAoHmzcz7oM1IUHnq2LEhuS5Ekr6-jXMigdhIkoqToT24ViygCmwlpZ1gnAfG6ajOOCebFwV2oCEjGb-gTd7G6TNew8mkgToIrM4ng9cUyaVBlH2jM4UvNSlvBqrgDBrMcmfy80l5gli_7Ej0h1oZ3LbcW-f3_q-WlnIzVrBSbsClEFtp-KpCsWe7iiVutUSA6vTOlI2MToBuHRiepcf56r3NHh_WC46xqjybP9AI7qnkf9KIu8OID2SplxsRGjsHAgL0-dnf3d8SLYDaZttgEfnJxjnUPFuXpbiS9BL3LsIVWDQ0LtN4bQrZuPVJvC1cv5ONmKG__o0yDQ8v2A90bK6_&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: I see what you mean, it is not as simple as the reverse. Thank you!

Comment: @BaklavaGain Yeah, sadly I have no idea of an easier way. Although, the sum is not to infinity but to bounded to $n$.